# S3 event not triggering/showing up in Lambda UI; built with Serverless CLI/serverless-plugin-existing-s3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, serverless, aws-serverless

The Lambda is not triggered by events and the event created does not appear in the Lambda GUI, though the SNS and SQS triggers do.

Here is the `serverless.yml` (note: I've removed my ARNs because I'm paranoid):

```
service: my-service

provider:
  name: aws
  runtime: python3.7
  iamRoleStatements:
    - Effect: "Allow"
      Action:
        - "s3:PutObject"
      Resource:
        Fn::Join:
          - ""
          - - "bucket-arn or *"

plugins:
  - serverless-plugin-existing-s3

layers:
  boto3_downgrade_layer:
    package:
      artifact: boto3_downgrade_layer.zip
    allowedAccounts:
      - '*'

functions:
  call_textract:
    handler: src/call_textract.lambda_handler
    description: "Kicks off the Textract process."
    events:
      - existings3:
          bucket: startrac-files
          event: s3:ObjectCreated:*
          rules:
            - prefix: input2/
            - suffix: .pdf
      - existings3:
          bucket: startrac-files
          event: s3:ObjectCreated:*
          rules:
            - prefix: input1/
            - suffix: .pdf
    layers:
      - arn

  get_textract_output:
    handler: src/get_textract_output.lambda_handler
    description: "Retrieves the Textracted data and writes it to a file to S3."
    events:
      - sqs: arn
    layers:
      - arn

  parse_textract_output:
    handler: src/parse_textract_output.lambda_handler
    description: "Parses the Textracted output and performs file ops in S3 based on the results."
    events:
      - sns: arn
    layers:
      - arn
```

To deploy, I run `sls deploy -v` and then `sls s3deploy` as per the docs (no errors), but no love. I should see the S3 event trigger in the Lambda's Configuration section of the UI (as I see the SQS/SNS triggers there), but I don't.

I could very well be using Serverless wrong here as I just discovered it today.

Edit 1: Just wanted to specify that my Function called `call_textract` should be **triggered by an S3 event**, not trigger the event.

Edit 2: I updated my code as suggested. The event trigger showed up in my GUI, except it's on the right (triggered by), not on the left of the Function where I need it. Seems like I'm using Lambda wrong here.

Comment: Why did you remove the `GetBucketNotification` and `PutBucketNotification` from your `iamRoleStatements`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to indent your `bucket`, `events` (with `s`, not `event`) and `rules` keys (those are properties of your `existingS3` event), like this:

```yml
functions:
  call_textract:
    handler: src/call_textract.lambda_handler
    description: "Kicks off the Textract process."
    events:
      - existingS3: # capital S
          bucket: startrac-files # defined under existingS3
          events:
            - s3:ObjectCreated:*
          rules:
            - prefix: input2/
            - suffix: .pdf
```

You also need the right statements in `iamRoleStatements` (in addition to your other statements):

```yaml
provider:
  name: aws
  iamRoleStatements:
    ...
    - Effect: "Allow"
      Action:
        - "s3:GetBucketNotification"
        - "s3:PutBucketNotification"
      Resource:
        Fn::Join:
          - ""
          - - "arn:aws:s3:::BUCKET_NAME or *"
```

Comment: `existingS3` with a capital `S` not `existings3`, see my comment in the code snippet above.